# Pulling key value from dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

Thanks to everyone that has helped me to this point. I am still in need of some additional help. I have the following dict structure that I pull in from device_config: 
{'GigabitEthernet': [{'name': '1', 'ip': {'address': {'primary': {'address': '192.168.200.200', 'mask': '255.255.255.0'}}, 'Cisco-IOS-XE-ospf:router-ospf': {'ospf': {'authentication': {'key-chain': 'sv-10599'}, 'message-digest-key': [{'id': 1, 'md5': {'auth-key': 'cisco'}}], 'network': {'point-to-point': [None]}}}}, 'mop': {'enabled': False, 'sysid': False}, 'Cisco-IOS-XE-ethernet:negotiation': {'auto': True}}, {'name': '2', 'shutdown': [None], 'mop': {'enabled': False, 'sysid': False}, 'Cisco-IOS-XE-ethernet:negotiation': {'auto': True}}, {'name': '3', 'shutdown': [None], 'mop': {'enabled': False, 'sysid': False}, 'Cisco-IOS-XE-ethernet:negotiation': {'auto': True}}]}

I am trying to create an if statement to detect if ‘auth-key’ is present and configured under an interface. I tried to define a variable `ospf_auth = interface_type_gig['ip']['Cisco-IOS-XE-ospf:router-ospf']['ospf']['message-digest-key'][0]` but it gives a KeyError on `['Cisco-IOS-XE-ospf:router-ospf']` same error in this format below with the if statement.

```
# import functions
from cisco_xe_api import *

# define variables
device_config = api_get_conf()

for interface_type_gig in device_config['Cisco-IOS-XE-native:native']['interface']['GigabitEthernet']:
    if 'message-digest-key' in interface_type_gig['ip']['Cisco-IOS-XE-ospf:router-ospf']['ospf']:
        ospf_auth = interface_type_gig['ip']['Cisco-IOS-XE-ospf:router-ospf']['ospf']['message-digest-key'][0]['md5']
        print(ospf_auth.keys)
```

Comment: What is the error? That's a decent amount of code, please provide a [mcve]. Also, `import *` is generally bad practice.

Comment: I updated the question with the code you requested. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the full `traceback`?

Comment: if 'message-digest-key' in interface_type_gig['ip']['Cisco-IOS-XE-ospf:router-ospf']['ospf']:
KeyError: 'Cisco-IOS-XE-ospf:router-ospf'

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] in the question itself. Right now you're missing the error message and the definition of `device_config`. Also is the structure of the data actually relevant? Seems like you're having a problem with just one part/level of it.

Comment: I updated the script again. The structure of the data is what I get from an API call. It dumps a configuration into a dict structure and from that I am trying to validate something is configured. In this case I am trying to verify that auth-key is present under GigabitEthernet 1. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work through the problem.

```
for interface_type_gig in device_config['Cisco-IOS-XE-native:native']['interface']['GigabitEthernet']:
    if 'ip' in interface_type_gig:
        if 'Cisco-IOS-XE-ospf:router-ospf' in interface_type_gig['ip']:
            ospf_presence = interface_type_gig['ip']['Cisco-IOS-XE-ospf:router-ospf']['ospf']
            #print(ospf_presence.keys())
            if 'message-digest-key' in ospf_presence:
                auth_presence = ospf_presence['message-digest-key'][0]['md5']
                #print(auth_presence.keys())
                if 'auth-key' in auth_presence:
                    print('MD5 Authentication Enabled!')
```